# Archive Path in IIS Media Services

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azure-media-services

I am running a azure windows virtual machine with IIS Media Services.
I am using this vm as a media server. It is used to create my publish point s for live and on-demand videos.

Here I'm having a very critical problem with "Archive Path".
We can set the archive path setting from the IIS manager. The default path is : %systemdrive%\inetpub\media\archives and we can chenge it to any othe available system or network drive.

As I already mentioned that I'm using this vm as a media server and definitely it will have thoudands of videos of large size. And storing these video on the limited size storage drive will be problamatic.

So finally I decided to set the archive path to my azure storage path (http://MY_STORAGEblob.core.windows.net/).

Have a look on it : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/266549

Please let me know how can I do this. I am hoping for a quick answer.

Thanks
Dev

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in solution in **IIS Media Services** which can use Windows Azure Blob Storage as an Archive Path. To archive files in **IIS Media Services** you must have a drive (local or network) mounted to local file system on which IIS Media Services components can write those files. And this could be considered the limitation within IIS Media Service at this point.

So if you want to use Windows Azure Blob Storage as your archive destination to IIS Media Services, you would need to find a solution which can mount the Azure Blob Storage as local drive. And that could be the one of many solutions to you.

I know one 3rd party solution provided by [Gladinet](http://www.gladinet.com/), in which you can mount Windows Azure Blob Storage as local drive as shown below. This could be used as a solution in your situation. I haven't used it so I am not sure about perf and other things so you may need to evaluate it thoroughly first before making final decision.

[image]

Comment: Hi Avkash, can I add 6+ TB size Gladinet Cloud Drive on Windows Azure Virtual machine? I am having Small size VM so that as per the windows azure I can add 2-3 drives of 1 TB each.